# 'alert' an object property on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, properties, alert, javascript-objects

I have a constructor which I then make the object library_science1 with:

```
function librarytech(humanity,food,wood,metal,wealth)
{
this.humanity=humanity;
this.food=food;
this.wood=wood;
this.metal=metal;
this.wealth=wealth;
}

var library_science1=new librarytech(0,200,200,0,0);
```

I have this as a click function:

```
$("[id^='library_']").click(function() {
var idd = this.id;
            alert(idd);
});
```

where the html is simply

```
<span id='library_science1'></span>
```

The code above works fine, alerting 'library_science1' nicely... it even works when I use the alert to directly pull one of the objects properties.

```
$("[id^='library_']").click(function() {
            alert(library_science1.food);
});
```

But I have many library_[SOMETHING] objects, corresponding each to there own 
`<span id="library_[SOMETHING]"></span>` line.

I'm trying to pull the objects properties depending on which one is clicked. Such as:

```
$("[id^='library_']").click(function() {
            alert(this.id.food);
});
```

or

```
$("[id^='library_']").click(function() {
    var x = this.id;
            alert(x.food);
});
```

The end purpose being that I can ultimately do things like:

```
foodamount -= this.id.food
```

Why isn't this working :/ :(

Comment: do you mean: `window[this.id].food` ???

Comment: Aren't you mixing variable's names and span id's ?

Comment: @A.Wolff I tried that, didn't help at all, maybe elaborate a bit?

Comment: If your variables are global, you could access it using : `window[this.id]`

Comment: @NathanP. Yes, but surely doing that means I can pull the objects properties because the object name matches with the span ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply because you are accessing an object in your first example and not a DOM object as in other, if their obejtos are global so you can access

```
alert(window[this.id].food);
```

or

```
alert(eval(this.id + ".food"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a test here using eval() and this works:

```
$("[id^='library_']").click(function() {
            alert(eval(this.id).food);
});

$("[id^='library_']").click(function() {
    var x = eval(this.id);
            alert(x.food);
});
```